# Schema relations: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

So I'm trying to make some realtions with mongoose. But when it comes to saving one schema to an other I get this error:

`Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters`

Here are some similar Schemas:

```
mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const userSchema = new Schema({
    _id: String,
    role: {
        type: String,
        default: 'Player'
    },
    tags: {
        type: [Schema.Types.ObjectId],
        ref: 'Tag'
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
```

```
mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const tagSchema = new Schema({
    _id: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    color: {
        type: String,
        default: '#2476d1'
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Tag', tagSchema)
```

And how I'm trying to link

```
try {
    const tag = await Tag.findOne({_id: 'Noob'})

    user.tags.push(tag.id)
    await user.save()
} catch (err) {
    console.error(`ERROR: ${user._id} at Noob check`)
    console.error(err)
}
```

According to other posts I've also tried pushing the `_id` like that:

```
user.tags.push(mongoose.ObjectID(tag._id))
// and
user.tags.push(mongoose.ObjectID.createFromHexString('4e6f6f62')) // just 'Noob' in hex
```

And I still get that error. How can I create a reference with a custom `_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have a type mis-match, an [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) has certain structure restriction for Mongo. The string `4e6f6f62` does not match these restrictions.

Just change your user schema `tags` field to string:

```
tags: {
        type: String,
        ref: 'Tag'
    }
```

And just keep the creation as is without trying to cast the string into `ObjectId`. If for some reason there's a specific reason you want it to be `ObjectId` you'll have to re-save the tag collection and conver the `_id` to a valid `ObjectId` format.